# When I swipe, let UIImageView and UIScrollView go below in same speed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

When I swipe right direction in iPhone(iOS 7.0), 
I want let UIImageView and UIScrollView go below in same speed.
 I sccuessfully made UIScrollView as subClass. (I instanced UIScrollView as "sv" in the code)
Now, UIImageView and UIScrollView go below differently.
May I ask what should I do to ?

```
if ( distanceHorizontal > distanceVertical ) {
    if ( _tEnded.x > _tBegan.x ) {
        // Swipe Right
        NSLog(@"Swipe Right");

        swipeSpeed = distanceHorizontal / dt;
        speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", swipeSpeed];
        NSInteger swipeSpeedChanged = swipeSpeed / 200;
        NSInteger x = 200 + swipeSpeedChanged;

        NSLog(@"swipeSpeedChanged：%d",  swipeSpeedChanged);
        headSpinImageView.center = CGPointMake(160,200);
        CGPoint offset;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];

        headSpinImageView.center = CGPointMake(160,x);

        //Scroll UIScrollView
        offset.x = 0.0f;
        offset.y = swipeSpeedChanged;
        [sv setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];

        headSpinRect = CGRectMake(160, 200, x, 60);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just use `[UIView animateWithDuration:` and set them both to have the same distance end point? The animation should handle them moving down at the same rate. For example, `UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:1.5 options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
animations:^{ self.imageView.frame = self.imageView.frame w/ .y + 800; self.uiscrollView.frame = self.uiscrollView.frame w/ .y + 800;}`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, somehow, I could solve this issue by below.[sv setContentOffset:offset animated:YES]; →　[sv setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];　　　 Thank you for the advice !